# I want to have a printable webpage which contains a curriculum from a database how can i make it presentable?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't make a webpage that will only print the text I need. For example I don't want to print the header file of my page only its body. How can I do that? thx!

Comment: only put on the page what you wanted printed and\or use a print specific stylesheet, you can use that to not show the header on print, but to still show if for web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [style sheet for print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) and hide (or otherwise restyle) the elements you don't want to print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

> We have a style sheet, `print.css`, which has been restricted to the `print` medium with the use of the attribute `media`.

Comment: hmnn so the only text that will be printed is those who are within the print.css?

Comment: no, you specify what styles to be used when the output is printed.